# maven-jdocbook-plugin coordinates and dependencies

Tags: maven, docbook

I am attempting to run docbook using maven-jdocbook-plugin with maven 3.

With a minimal configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jdocbook-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-cli</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>compile</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/doc/xml</sourceDirectory>
    <sourceDocumentName>DocBook.xml</sourceDocumentName>
    <formats>
      <format>
        <formatName>html</formatName>
        <finalName>index.html</finalName>
      </format>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I get the following error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-plugin:2.3.8:generate (default-cli) on project <project>: Execution default-cli of goal org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-plugin:2.3.8:generate failed: could not locate resource [/html/chunk.xsl] -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-plugin:2.3.8:generate (default-cli) on project <project>: Execution default-cli of goal org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-plugin:2.3.8:generate failed: could not locate resource [/html/chunk.xsl]
```

When I look in my local maven repository I see:

```
$ ls ~/.m2/repository/net/sf/docbook/docbook-xsl
$ 1.76.1
$ ls ~/.m2/repository/net/sf/docbook/docbook-xsl/1.76.1
$ _maven.repositories       docbook-xsl-1.76.1.pom      docbook-xsl-1.76.1.pom.sha1
```

So there is a POM but no library.

If a I give an explicit dependency for docbook-xsl, it does download content (but I still get the same error):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>docbook-xsl</artifactId>
  <version>1.76.1</version>
  <classifier>ns-resources</classifier>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

The only way I get it to actually generate anything is to give it a version of docbook-xsl which has a jar not a zip:

```
<groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
<artifactId>docbook-xsl-ns</artifactId>
<version>1.74.0</version>
```

How do I get the zip version of the XSL templates to work with this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted yourself, put in the dependency of type zip:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
    <artifactId>docbook-xsl</artifactId>
    <version>1.76.1</version>
    <classifier>ns-resources</classifier>
    <type>zip</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

All you need to do on top of that is configure the `<stylesheetResource>` within the maven-jdocbook-plugin using a suitable `classpath:/` URI:

```
<format>
  <formatName>html</formatName>
  <stylesheetResource>classpath:/docbook/html/chunk.xsl</stylesheetResource>
</format>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my own solution to the question:

The docbook-xsl library with jar packaging (1.74.0) is automatically included in the classpath of the maven-jdocbook-plugin when it runs.

The version with zip packaging (1.76.1) is not, and needs to be unzipped manually. I used the maven-dependency-plugin for this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-docbook-xsl</id>
  <phase>generate-resources</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
            <artifactId>docbook-xsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.76.1</version>
            <type>zip</type>
            <classifier>ns-resources</classifier>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I pointed the maven-jdocbook-plugin at the styles sheets in this package:

```
<formats>
  <format>
    <formatName>html</formatName>
    <stylesheetResource>file:${project.build.directory}/docbook/html/chunk.xsl</stylesheetResource>
    <finalName>index.html</finalName>
  </format>
  <format>
    <formatName>pdf</formatName>
    <stylesheetResource>file:${project.build.directory}/docbook/fo/docbook.xsl</stylesheetResource>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.pdf</finalName>
  </format>
  <format>
    <formatName>html_single</formatName>
    <stylesheetResource>file:${project.build.directory}/docbook/html/docbook.xsl</stylesheetResource>
    <finalName>index.html</finalName>
  </format>
</formats>
```

I'd welcome any suggestions for short cuts to this process.